# pagination not working in php query

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

hi I am trying to create pagination for a mysql query but it is not really working at all, can somebody tell me where is my mistake ?  Here is my code so far.

```
<?php     

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","database","password","table");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (!$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_name"))
{
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
$per_page =5;//define how many games for a page
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$pages = ceil($count/$per_page);

   if(!isset($_GET['page']) || 
   $_GET['page']=="") {
      $page="1";
} else {
  $page=$_GET['page'];
}    $start    = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cursos LIMIT $start,$per_page");
```

This is my part where I am listing the results from the my sql query

```
?>

// show results from my sql query 

<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   $id = $row['id'];
?>


// code for next page
```

And finally this is the pagination links at the bottom of the page

```
//Show page links
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
{?>
  <li id="<?php echo $i;?>"><a href="cursos.php?c=<?php echo $c;?>&page=<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
<?php  } ?>
```

After the suggestion by Deepak I am getting now only

erro on the final code  `//Show page` it generates fake link 
**Notice**:  Undefined variable: c in **D:\xampp\htdocs\cedecap\admin\cursos.php** on line **191**
&page=1">1

And the code //Show page links is not showing anything. The pages are now 5 on the page that is working

Comment: Can you please explain more what you mean by not working?

Comment: if($_GET['page']==""){
$page="1";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following line

```
$result = $result." LIMIT $start,$per_page";
```

To

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT $start,$per_page");
```

**EDIT**

In the line `$query_count=mysqli_query($con, $result);` you are passing result of `mysql_query()` again to the same function. You can skip that line and do the following:

```
//$query_count=mysqli_query($con, $result); this line is deleted

$per_page =5;//define how many games for a page
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$pages = ceil($count/$per_page);
```

Also make the following changes to get rid of `index` error:

```
if(!isset($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page']=="") {
  $page="1";
} else {
  $page=$_GET['page'];
}
```

For undefined variable `$c` error add the following code after setting up `$page` variable:

```
if(!isset($_GET['c']) || $_GET['c']=="") {
  $c="some value";
} else {
  $c=$_GET['c'];
}
```

Comment: thoose chnages fixed everything now, except the part of the pages when I click on any other pages it get's me to <a href="linktoyourfile?c=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: c in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\cedecap\admin\cursos.php</b> on line <b>191</b><br />
&page=1">1</a>

Comment: Where did you define the variable `$c` in your code and what is the value of it ?

Comment: I don't have such a variable in my code, when I add the last edition with it stops working at all gives me errors again

Comment: You are passing `$c` in your pagination link. But you have NEVER defined such variable anywhere. When you say `<?php echo $c;?>` what do you expect the `PHP` to echo ?

Comment: probably I should erase it since I don't need it at all

Comment: Yes then get rid of it and it should start working!!

Comment: I did erase it and my code for the link now is the following: <?php echo $i;?>"><a href="crusos.php?page=<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?>  - which code shows the link correct: crusos.php?page=2   but when I click it it goes to Object not found!

Comment: fixed I had a typo in the url

Comment: @JohnSiniger no worries!!

Answer (score 1):

Many errors, to a start

```
mysql_num_rows($query_count);
```

should be

```
mysqli_num_rows($query_count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using mysql_* commands instead of the mysqli_*

You are using them in a couple of places:

```
$query_count=mysql_query($result);

$count = mysql_num_rows($query_count);
```

Convert these to:

```
 $query_count=mysqli_query($con, $result);

 $count = mysqli_num_rows($query_count);
```

Along with the problem that @deepak pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're appending " LIMIT $start, $per_page" to your result object rather than to the base SQL statement.  Try assigning your query to a variable up top, and then appending to that variable like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
if (!$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
}

$query_count=mysqli_query($con,$result);

$per_page =5;//define how many games for a page
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query_count);
$pages = ceil($count/$per_page);

if($_GET['page']==""){
    $page="1";
}else{
    $page=$_GET['page'];
}
$start    = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$result     = mysqli_query($con,$sql." LIMIT $start,$per_page");
```

Comment: made those changes and he other above the only think which is better is that now is showing 5 results but it is showing the 3 errors and it is  not showing the pages of the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this line is wrong:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","database","password","table");
```

Should be this way:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd");
```

Try with:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","isuposseyouruserisroot","youdatabasepass","nameofyourdatabase") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: with that edit the query is not listing anything and it is showing additional error: Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\xampp\htdocs\cedecap\admin\cursos.php on line 51
Error:

Comment: That is the correct order to a mysqli_connect: first your host, then the user, the password, the database ;)